# Is there any way to "hide" a Kotlin function from Retrofit annotation processor?

Tags: java, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines, annotation-processing

I have a few interfaces that looks something like the following:

```
interface ApiInterface : Context.Element {
    @GET(Urls.url)
    suspend fun getSomeData(): Data
}

interface Context.Element {
    operator fun plus(context: Context): Context
}
```

I am trying to implement a `Context` implementation in similar way of the *Kotlin* `CoroutineContext`. As I am trying to add my Retrofit http interface as a `Context.Element` it ends up inheriting some other functions. The code compiles and runs fine until I call a function from my ApiInterface instance which inherits from `Context.Element` therefore doesn't have any `@GET`, `@POST` or any retrofit annotation.

If I run the following code:

```
val context = ApiInterfaceImpl()
context + DifferentApiInterfaceImpl()
```

I receive a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HTTP method annotation is required (e.g., @GET, @POST, etc.). for method Context.plus`.

I believe that if I am able to make the Retrofit annotation processor to skip the functions inherited from `Context.Element` this problem would be solved. Is there any way to to this? Any `@Transient` like annotation for functions? I tried to use `@JvmSynthetic` but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is not in annotation processor, but in the way Retrofit works. It doesn't generate an implementation class, but creates a [proxy object](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/Retrofit.java#L140) at runtime and this proxy object handles all method calls and routes them to the proper handler. So obviously it can't handle a non-service method. Also it's not clear how you would provide an implementation for that non-annotated method.
So I would say it's currently impossible.

**Edit:**
As you are using default method on interface to provide the implementation, it should generally work I believe, because `Retrofit` handles default methods separately. The issue here might be that `Retrofit` knows about java default methods only and by default kotlin does not use them (for compatibility with java 7 and below). So if you make the compiler generate java default method, it should work. Please check out [this post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/07/kotlin-1-4-m3-generating-default-methods-in-interfaces/) for details.

Comment: I see. Thanks, food to know... I always thought it was backed by a generated implementation class. By the way, the way I provided the implementation for the non-annotated method (the `plus()`) was just by having a default implementation in the interface.
The problem of not being able to make the retrofit interface extend my `Context` interface is that I'm not able to have the same `Key` for the `ApiInterface` implementation present in my `Context`. Trying to figure out a nice way to do that. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @admqueiroga Please check out the updated answer.

Comment: I think that's exactly what I need. Trying to add the `-Xjvm-default=enable` to the Kotlin project but now I have to deal with `Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.` I guess once I figure out where to add the argument it will work. Right now I am adding like `kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += listOf("-Xjvm-default=enable")` but it's breaking the JVM. Thanks again for the help @esentsov! Really appreciate!

Comment: If I don't set `kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += listOf("-Xjvm-default=enable")` the IDE displays an error wherever I am using `@JvmDefault`. When I do set this flag the errors disappears but the JVM can't be created due to `Unrecognized option: -Xjvm-default`. Using Gradle by the way

Comment: Have you also set `jvmTarget = "1.8"` for kotlin and `sourceCompatibility`, `targetCompatibility` to `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8`?

Comment: Yeah, the fault was on me. While figuring out where to add the flag (either on gradle or intellij) I ended up adding on both but with a typo in the intellij settings. After removing it worked. Thanks again for you time!